# How to write a pre-commit hook to run functional tests for java

Tags: java, bash, github, pre-commit-hook

i want to write a pre-commit hook for my java code where i can run my functional tests and unit tests separately.something in a bash script,Here is a code i am using to prevent commits on Sundays.

```
if [ date +%w -eq 6 ]; then
  echo "Enjoy your life. Do not work on Sunday!"
  exit 1
  fi
  exit 0
```

something like that to run tests before committing the code into github.

Comment: This looks more like batch

Comment: i know it is not java but i want someone help me to write code in java for pre-commit or if can't then will be happy with bash script also. Thanks

Comment: Show what you've tried in java (Code)

Comment: well i haven't got it yet was asking is it possible if not then can anyone help me to get a bash script for it? apologies and thanks

Comment: So you're looking for a program that checks the date, and if its not sunday then it will commit code to github?

Comment: @UnknownOctopus thanks for the reply, well the above example is currently working fine for date what i want is a case where i run all my tests before committing to github saying like " echo running unit tests<test  suite name> ..." or echo "running functional test<test suite name>" something like date before committing.and if it fails it should not commit.Thanks in advance

Comment: Ah i see now, you want a program that will run multiple tests before you submit it, do you need it in bash or is batch alright?

Comment: @UnknownOctopus yes in bash will prefer thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry i couldn't provide an answer in bash as i'm unfamiliar with the language, i can provide the following in batch.

```
@ECHO OFF

:Main
set MYDATE=%DATE:~0,3%
if %MYDATE% == Sun ( 
goto Sunday
) else ( goto Test1 )

:Sunday
echo Enjoy your life. Do not work on Sunday!
pause
exit

:Test1
echo Running tests...
::Your test code here
IF %Test1% == PassTest ( 
goto Test2 
) else ( goto Error )

:Test2
echo Running tests...
::Your test code here
if %Test2% == PassTest (
goto Commit
) else ( goto Error )

:Commit
::Script to commit your code

:Error
ECHO "One or more of the tests have failed."
pause
exit
```

As you can see i just used if statements to check if the tests were successfull or not (of course you can setup these tests by writing the code in the `::Your test code goes here section`). [This](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html) is a website that may help you convert the batch to bash, or if you cannot, hopefully another user on stackoverflow will assist you. Like i said i apologize that i couldn't get you the code in the language you wanted. Hope this helps.